# How to assign max value to input field depending on option selected from dropdown box in ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

View code:

```html
<label class="item item-input item-select" name="documenttype">
                <i class="icon ion-man placeholder-icon"></i>
                    <span class="input-label" style="color:#aeb1b7"> Document Type</span>
                   <select name="documenttype" ng-model="documenttype" ng-change="docid()" required>
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
                        <option value="aadhar">Aadhaar card</option>
                        <option value="driving">Driving License</option>
                        <option value="voting">Voting Card</option>
                        <option value="pancard">PAN Card</option>
                        <option value="rationcard">Ration card</option>
                        <option value="passport">Indian Passport</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="controls">   
                            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && indexcard.documenttype.$error.required"><h4 style="color:red;"><i class="icon ion-alert-circled custom-icon"></i></h4></span>
                    </div>
                </label>
<label class="item item-input" name="documentid" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;">

                        <i id="iconcolor" class="icon ion-person placeholder-icon"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="documentid" min="{{doc_id}}" 
                        max="{{doc_id}}" placeholder="Document ID" ng-model="documentid" autocomplete="off" required />

                        <div class="controls">   
                            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && indexcard.documentid.$error.required"><h4><i class="icon ion-alert-circled custom-icon"></i></h4></span>

                        </div>
                </label>
```

Controller code:

```js
$scope.docid = function() {

  if ($scope.documenttype == "aadhar") {

    $scope.doc_id = 12;

  }
  if ($scope.documenttype == "pancard") {

    $scope.doc_id = 10;

  }
}
```

I am working with ionic 1 angularjs . Basically I want to add a max limit to input field documentid depending on option selected in dropdown. I am using `ng-change` and calling a function where the condition is written to set max value. But its not working.Can any one guide me to know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem in depth? I mean that what type of problem you have faced? If possible then please share your problem in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are trying to use "max" and "min" attributes for an input of type "text". Those attributes only work for inputs of type "number".

For an input of type "text", use the "maxlength" attribute instead.

Otherwise, your AngularJS code is correct, and everything should work as you expected simply by changing "max" to "maxlength".